# Background image with fading edges

Tags: android, user-interface

I tried to put background image to linearlayout in my android project. All is working nicely except those fading edges in the left and right on the screen. My background image dimensions are 52x602 and don't have such fading edge originally. I want the background image to cover all the area. Also it has done by designer and using 9-patch I think (black border around image). How can I set the background correctly without those edges?

In emulator it looks like this:

[image]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/login_background"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you question is not very clear... do you want to remove the fadings on the left and right? Isn't that just a simple photoshop / paint job?

Comment: in my background image there's no black fading edges, so I have none to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got answer myself. The .png files must have .9.png ending if they are 9-patch files...So if someone will have same problem, then you'll know.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting fadingEdge to none

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/login_background"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:fadingEdge="none"
  >
</LinearLayout>
```